# angularjs not updating input on mobile

Tags: angularjs, input, refresh

in my angular controller's scope I have an array and variable for traversing this array

```
$scope.items = [
    {Name: 'X'},
    {Name: 'Y'},
    {Name: 'Z'}
];
$scope.currentItemIdx = 0;
$scope.currentItem = $scope.items[$scope.currentItemIdx];

function setCurrent(){
    $scope.currentItemIdx++;
    $scope.currentItem = $scope.items[$scope.currentItemIdx];
}
```

in my view I've got an input bound to currentItem

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="currentItem.Name">
```

and on the desktop everything works as expected - when I call `setCurrent()` the currentItem moves forward and the input value is: X then Y then Z

the problems begin when I run this in Chrome on mobile device - sometimes the input will show proper Name, and sometimes it won't update. ex.:
`currentItemIdx = 0`, the input value is X
I call `setCurrent()`
`currentItemIdx = 1`, the input value is Y
I call `setCurrent()`
`currentItemIdx = 2`, the input value is Y, but when I focus the input (tap it) the value changes to Z

I tried adding `$scope.$apply()` in `setCurrent()` - doesn't work
Also I tried displaying the Name not in an input

```
<div>{{currentItem.Name}}</div>
```

and it shows the correct value! (right beside the input with the incorrect value)
so it seems like just some input-ngmodel-refreshTheValue-issue

has anyone had similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!---Try Changing Your Input Type From Number To text-------->
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="currentItem.Name">
```